# Bruteforce python shuffle function

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, cryptography, shuffle

Hello I was wondering how to revert a string that was shuffled with the random.shuffle() function from python.
I know that the original string was shuffled with this code:

```
import random

file_to_shuffle = list(open("file_tot_shuffle.txt", "rb").read().strip()) #rile containing a string
random.seed(random.randint(0, 256))
random.shuffle(file_to_shuffle)
print(bytes(file_to_shuffle).decode())
```

Thanks to anyone that can help

Comment: Perhaps keep a copy of the original data?

Comment: Thanks but I wan’t to find another solution.

Comment: @quamrana I've added a solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

Let me know if this is what you're looking for:

```
import random

file_contents = list("Something")

# Get seed for the code
seed = random.randint(0, 256)
random.seed(seed)
random.shuffle(file_contents)

# Re-Inject Same seed
indices = list(range(len(file_contents)))
random.seed(seed)
random.shuffle(indices)

# To Revert
collat = sorted(list(zip(indices, file_contents)), key=lambda x: x[0])

print("".join(list(zip(*collat))[1]))
```

**P.S. This works due to the psuedo random algorithm, which is not true randomness**

Comment: Thanks it's what I was searching for :)

Answer (score -1):

The issue if the original seed is known or not. If we know it, you can reverse the shuffle by figuring how *how* that seed shuffles a list of that length.

```
import random

# file_to_shuffle = list(open("file_tot_shuffle.txt", "rb").read().strip()) #rile containing a string
file_to_shuffle = list(b"HI THIS IS SOME RANDOM TEXT".strip())

SEED = random.randint(0, 256)

random.seed(SEED)
random.shuffle(file_to_shuffle)
print(bytes(file_to_shuffle).decode())

order = list(range(len(file_to_shuffle)))
random.seed(SEED)
random.shuffle(order)

unshuffledList = [0]*len(order)
for i, orig_i in enumerate(order):
    unshuffledList[orig_i] = file_to_shuffle[i]

print(bytes(unshuffledList).decode())
```

Output:

```
MIR OION EH TST HSMEASITDX
HI THIS IS SOME RANDOM TEXT
```

If we don't know the seed, we at least know it's somewhere in the range of 0 to 256... so there may be a way to reverse it if something more is known about the original file.

Comment: I've added the same answer already

Comment: Yes, we start with the same general idea, but my way 1) Uses the same byte type input as OP. 2) Is more clear about *what* is happening to unshuffle, rather than throwing zips and lambdas around. 3) Shows output. 4) Give a, albeit limited, explanation of what's happening.